# Close current UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls, parent, children

I have a Window1.xaml main Window; and after some event, I display a UserControl EditFile.xaml.

The code behind is:

```
public static int whichSelected = -1;
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //searchEditPanel.Children.Clear();
    whichSelected = listViewFiles.SelectedIndex;
    searchEditPanel.Children.Add(_EditFileControle);        //this is Grid
}
```

And now, how can I close the opened/added UserControl from its content by clicking a Cancel button or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
searchEditPanel.Children.Remove(_EditFileControle);
```

Another Suggestion:

Maybe this helps: http://sachabarber.net/?p=162

if it doesn't: Add a property to your UserControl:

```
public UserControl ParentControl {get;set;}
```

Now modify your code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //searchEditPanel.Children.Clear();
    whichSelected = listViewFiles.SelectedIndex;
    _EditFileControle.ParentControl = this;
    searchEditPanel.Children.Add(_EditFileControle);        //this is Grid
}
```

Now you should be able to do this:

```
 // Somewhere in your UserControl
if (this.ParentControl != null)
    this.ParentControl.Children.Remove(this);
```

Comment: Yes - that works, but running from parent (Window1). I must close UserControl from my children (EditFile.xaml.cs file) by clicking on it some Cancel button.

Answer (score 18):

```
Window.GetWindow(this).Close();
```

You don't need to use a new variable, you can use it directly.

Comment: Just wondering ... will this cause the `UserControl.Unloaded` event to raise?

Comment: "'Window' does not contain a definition for 'GetWindow'". Does the class need to inherit from Window or UserControl?

Answer (score 3):

In your button click handler try :

```
Window parentWindow = (Window)this.Parent;
parentWindow.Close();
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the **Visibility** property of the control you want to "close" to **Collapsed**.

This way it will not be displayed anymore but will still be present in the visual tree if you need to reuse it later.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    (this.Parent as searchEditPanel).Children.Remove(this);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.