# Closing a UserControl in a Grid of MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I am trying to close a usercontrol with a button click.
The usercontrol is in a grid of the mainwindow.

This is how i open it and it works.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        UsLogin _UsLogin = new UsLogin();
        OpenUserControl(_UsLogin);

    }

    private void OpenUserControl(UsLogin _UsLogin)
    {
        grdVensters.Children.Add(_UsLogin);
    }
}
```

Now in the usercontrol i have a button to confirm the login.
(no code yet this just a mockup to show in class how i want it to look)
I want this button to close this usercontrol in grdVensters so I have my main window ready.

I can't seem to access grdVensters in my usercontrol. Can i make a link?

tried: [Close current UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949089/close-current-usercontrol) 
but best answer closes MainWindow what i don't want.

This looks like what i need but can't make it work in my case. [Causing a UserControl to remove itself (WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254213/causing-a-usercontrol-to-remove-itself-wpf)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Closing here could mean Show/Hide or removing it from grid's children collection. Best would be to set UC's Visibility property to collapsed at UC's side, otherwise you can traverse the tree up to access the grid. `VisualTreeHelper` class will help you in this.

Comment: Im not sure I get the issue completely but I understand  and agree with Mat. Other solution could be to pass an action to the control. On clicking the button in the control simply invoke the action. You can pass the action in the constructor or just expose it via a property. In the Action's implementation (residing in the Main window class) call `grdVensters.Children.Remove(_UsLogin);`. This shouldnt take musch sweating to do. To be honest I would go MVVM since you are using WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really go for MVVM if you want to work with WPF. There are tons of resources on the web. However, I've created a small example that should lead you to the right direction. You can show/hide the login view by setting the correlating property on the ViewModel. The `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` converts the `bool` value to a `Visibility` value. I also added a CheckBox to demonstrate a simple example how you could change the visible state.

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="bToV" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsLoginVisible, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Button Content="Login"
            Visibility="{Binding Path=IsLoginVisible, Converter={StaticResource bToV}}" />
    <!--<yournamespace:UsLogin Visibility="{Binding Path=IsLoginVisible, Converter={StaticResource bToV}}/>-->
</StackPanel>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow  
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isLoginVisible;
    public bool IsLoginVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return _isLoginVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            _isLoginVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer. I am a student and we haven't covered MVVM yet (will in a few weeks) but this is a great example. Ty!

Comment: @JurgenVolders So you want to accept the answer? or give at least a upvote? ;-)

Comment: Sorry was my first question ever ;) I accepted and upvoted but since my rep atm is below 15 you won't see it I believe.